# CORS issue with localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am pretty new to developing and I am working on an app with node and express. I am having an issue where I get a:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[API_KEY]/38.7907,121.2358' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I do actually have the API key in the code within the project and I have been able to just copy/paste directly into Chrome and I get the data returned.

I'm just lost as to why it works from chrome, but not from my project.  Isn't chrome also my local machine? I think I may be able to use JSONP but I'm wondering if there is a better approach?

This is a link to the project on github: https://github.com/ryanmdoyle/BrainBreak

Comment: You should read [The FAQ for the API you are trying to use](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq#cross-origin)!

Comment: "Isn't chrome also my local machine?" — Your copy of Chrome is. Your visitor's copy of Chrome is not. Chrome only knows that it is a browser visiting a website. It does not know who controls that website.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin.  I had not previously found that answer.  (I've been looking at all sorts of things!)